# How is the overcharge protection working for USB-charged mini- LiPo packs

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I looked into my tiny bluetooth speaker ([LOGILINK SP0054BK](https://www.pollin.de/p/bluetooth-lautsprecher-logilink-sp0054bk-schwarz-641462)), and found that the board only contains a [5856ESE](https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/5856ESE), handling the bluetooth side of things, and a [NS4150](https://hubtronics.in/NS4150), handling the audio amplification, otherwise there are only resistors, caps, and some diodes - the energy is provided by a nondescript little silvery pack, that i guess is a LiPo pack. It is 20mm x 20mm x 5mm, and only has two leads. I cannot see a PCB through the Kapton. The charging is done via USB. I cannot follow the leads, because the whole board is multilayer and too crowded.

My question is: Do those packs themselves usually contain some overcharge protection circuit? Do they just put a resistor or diode in series with the 5V from USB to protect the LiPo from receiving more than 4.x V ?

Picture similar, only my pack is tinier and has no print:
[image: LiPo pack silvery, with tow leads and Kapton tape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very nice SOC chip with  DSP for low cost  (<<$1) and small instruction set (RISC) that does it all including 16 bit ADC to measure voltage and current to regulate LiPo battery charge.

https://github.com/RDA5981/RDA5856/blob/master/Datasheet/RDA5856TE_Datasheet_V0.03.pdf
[image]

[Tear-down](https://raspiblog.noblogs.org/post/tag/8002d/)

(perhaps a fine example of IP theft, RDA does not hold patents and relies on alliance provider, but I don't know)

Comment: I did not even stop to admire what this chip is capable of, how many PWM and GPIO it ahs besides it's (I assumed) bluetooth functionality. Eye opener, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes battery packs have a protection module, sometimes they don't.

Most likely they don't just put a diode in series with 5V, as that would damage the battery quite quickly and it might become dangerous. If that device is dangerous, then you can inform your local electrical safety authorities about it so the sellers have to make a product recall.